# Azure, get App service details from code .NET

Tags: azure, x509certificate

The following code run and get the App data when run on Azure App service.
Locally it throw exception that the certificate not authorized.
Is there any reason ?

If I create the certificate locally from string it works fine.

```
   public static CertificateCloudCredentials CredentialsProd; 
X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);


X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                           X509FindType.FindByThumbprint,
                           prodThumbprint,
                           false);

if (certCollection.Count > 0)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = certCollection[0];
    Credentials = new CertificateCloudCredentials(SUBSCRIPTION_ID, cert);
}
certStore.Close();


using (var client = new ComputeManagementClient(Credentials))
{      
     var t = client.HostedServices.GetDetailedAsync(serviceName, CancellationToken);
                        HostedServiceGetDetailedResponse detailedResponse = t.Result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate on the local machine must be install as .Pfx
just like it does in Azure.